# Remover coluna de números gerada automatica no Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Criei um dataframe no pandas, esta funcionando tudo perfeito, mas quando exporto pro Excel, ele aparece essa primeira coluna com esses números. Gostaria de remove-la, mas comandos como .drop não funcionam.[image: resultado no excel]

```py
df = {}
item = []
count = []
def dataframe(df):
    for i in ranking:
        item.append(i['item'])
        count.append(i['count'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=('Item','Count'))
    df['Item'] = item
    df['Count'] = count
    df.sort_values('Count', axis=0, ascending = False, inplace=True)
    df.to_excel('C:/hashtag_teste.xlsx')
    print(df)
    return df
```

Answer (score 4):

[Por padrão](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), `DataFrame.to_excel` salva o índice do seu DataFrame junto da tabela de Excel. O índice de um DataFrame (também por padrão) é uma sequência numérica começando de 0.

É fácil mudar este comportamento ao salvar o arquivo Excel. Simplesmente passe o argumento `index=False`:

```
df.to_excel('C:/hashtag_teste.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Eu achei que tivesse tentado isso, mas talvez estivesse colocando no lugar errado. Ainda estou aprendendo.

Muito Obrigado pela ajuda :)